# I need to parse json file 1 key 1 value

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file

```
{
"35673": [
        "234",
        "357",
        "123"
    ],
    "34566": [
        "333",
        "456",
        "789"
    ]
}
```

I parsed json to python dictionary format 1 key multiple values stored

```
'35673': ['234','357','123'],
 '34566': ['333','456','789].
```

How to parse in the dictionary json file format 1 key 1 value?

```
'35673':'234'
'35673':'357'
...
'34566':'333'
'34566':'456'
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. By that logic, when accessing a specific key, it wouldn't know which value to fetch..

Comment: as mentioned by @Diggy. each key in a dictionary has to be unique.  perhaps you may want to create tuples of the keys and the individual values of the corresponding lists?

Comment: it would help if you showed us the code that does the parsing.

Comment: each key value has to be unique. You cannot have the same key for value

Comment: In the final, I need to get a table in greenplum in the form of 1 key 1 value as it can be done through python from the resulting dictionary? ```'35673': ['234','357','123'],
 '34566': ['333','456','789].```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Each key should be unique. You cannot have the same key for the value. However, you can access each value like this:
For example if you want to access `456`. You can it like this:
First read the json file:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

so in order to read `456`, you can say `print(data["34566"])` which will print out:`['333','456','789]`. Then since I want to access `456`, which is the 1st index(counting from 0). I would have to say this:
`print(data["34566"][1])`. This prints out 456.

Another example:
Lets say that I want to print `123`. I would need to first see which key contains the list(In our case, its `35673`). Then, when we say `print(data["35673"])`. We get `['234','357','123']`. We can access 123(0th element)`print(data["35673"][0])`.
Basically in python, you cannot have the same key for a value. Even if you do(For example):

```
aDict = {
"hello":"bye",
"hello":"foo"

}
```

When you say `print(aDict["hello"])`, it will print the last element that has the key `hello`. So it would print `"foo"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the final, I need to get a table in greenplum in the form of 1 key 1 value as it can be done through python from the resulting dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in data:
    for i in range(len(data.get(key))):
        print(key, data.get(key)[i])
```

it was simple